# Is there a way to copy permissions from one user to another?

Tags: azure-devops

Pretty simple question all in title. Is there a way to copy project permissions from one user to another? Or, is there a way to copy group memberships from one user to another?

In regular Azure, you can use the console to accomplish tasks like this, but I have not been able to find anything with this level of control in DevOps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot do this in the Azure DevOps.

As a workaround, we could create a permission group and configure the group permission, then add these user to the same group, then these users will get the same permission.

Comment: Is there a way to copy group memebership from one AAD user to another?